# Remove the default Security Group assigned by Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk, security-groups

I have created a Elastic Beanstalk environment and have created this .config to edit the security groups which worked. Now my EC2s are attached to the new SG and the default one.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: SecurityGroups
    value: "sg-123456"
```

My question is: How can I remove the default security group attached to it bcz I don't want to use it.

Comment: Can you not just go to VPC -> Security Groups and delete it? Or do you mean within config/code?

Comment: I need to do it within config/code.
it's easy to do it in the console but I'm trying to automate the infrastructure.